# match and change the cases with condition in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I put in column `C` the Value True even if one of **Contract_Nr** in `B` is set to True otherwise FALSE? `LookUp` dose not work in that case because I have to check 2 columns.

[image]

I do not know how the command could be called even I have the problem to put the correct Title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,TRUE)>0,TRUE,"")
```

Comment: COUNTIF cannot have so many arguments! Maybe you mean COUNTIFS?!